# SET value SELECT FROM variable table

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I need to get the value from `SELECT` with variable table.

My code looks like this:

```
SET @count = @count + 1;
SET @count = CAST (@count AS varchar)

IF @pocet> 0 AND @pocet <= 9

BEGIN
    SET @tab_val_ = 'tabVal_00' + @count;
    SET @tabSta _ = 'tabSta_00' + @count;
    SET @var1 = (SELECT DESC_POINT FROM @tabSta_ WHERE id_w = @ id_w);
    print @ var1;
```

> Error
> Msg 1087, Level 16, State 1, Line 54
> Must declare the table variable "@tabSta_".

---

I'm sorry, I guess I spoke.

@tabSta_xxx is an actual table such as tabSta_001 and in the query `SET @var1 = (SELECT DESC_POINT FROM @tabSta_ WHERE id_w = @ id_w);` I need @var to be equal to DESC_POINT. For example, DESC_POINT is "abcdefg"

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you want to do.  Your code does not have a *table variable*.  It has what appears to be a string being misused as a table name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, here is the code, I need to get the value DESC_POINT from @table, which I will then need to add to the column name, which will no longer be a problem

````
SET @id_w = 50000269; --Comment
DECLARE @tbl_name varchar (100)
SET @tbl_name = 'tbl _' + @ id_w
DECLARE @tabSta_ varchar (20)

DECLARE @DropTable varchar (200)
SET @DropTable = 'DROP TABLE' + @ tbl_name


--DROP TABLE TempTableExport
IF OBJECT_ID ('' + @ tbl_name + '') IS NOT NULL EXEC (@DropTable)

DECLARE @CREATE VARCHAR (6144)
SET @CREATE = 'CREATE TABLE' + @ tbl_name + '(ID_R BIGINT, DATE date, TIME time (7), STT int, SV_P1 decimal (6,3))';
EXEC (@CREATE)


--DECLARE @id_w varchar (10) --id_w--
DECLARE @num_point int --number of points--
DECLARE @duplex int --number of points--
DECLARE @pocet int
DECLARE @pocet_d int
DECLARE @poceta_da varchar (3)
DECLARE @poceta varchar (3)
DECLARE @tab_val_ varchar (20)
DECLARE @Bod_ varchar (20)
DECLARE @ItemSQL VARCHAR (6144)
DECLARE @Alter VARCHAR (6144)
DECLARE @Alter_d VARCHAR (6144)
DECLARE @Insert VARCHAR (6144)
DECLARE @Update VARCHAR (6144)
DECLARE @Update_d VARCHAR (6144)
DECLARE @Cycle int
DECLARE @ var1 varchar (max)
Declare @sqla nvarchar (max)
--SET @id_w = 50000157; --Comment

SET @num_point = (SELECT NUM_POINT FROM tabSta_unit WHERE id_w = @ id_w);
SET @duplex = (SELECT MODE_WORK FROM tabSta_unit WHERE id_w = @ id_w);

SET @count = 0

WHILE @pocet <@num_point
BEGIN
SET @ count = @ count + 1;
SET @ count = CAST (@ count AS varchar)
IF @pocet> 0 AND @pocet <= 9
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal_00' + @ count;
SET @tabSta _ = 'tabSta_00' + @ count;
SET @ var1 = (SELECT DESC_POINT FROM @tabSta_ WHERE id_w = @ id_w);
print @ var1;
PRINT @tabSta_;
SET @ Bod_ = 'Bod_00' + @ count;
END
IF @pocet> = 10 AND @pocet <= 99
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal_0' + @ count;
SET @ Bod_ = 'Bod_0' + @ count;
END
IF @count * = 100
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal _' + @ count;
SET @ Point_ = 'Point _' + @ count;
END
SET @Alter = 'ALTER TABLE' + @ tbl_name + 'ADD' + @ Bod_ + 'decimal (6,3) NULL';
EXEC (@Alter)
END
SET @insert = 'INSERT INTO' + @ tbl_name + '(ID_R, DATE, TIME, SV_P1, STT) SELECT tabVal_unit.ID_R, tabVal_unit.DATE, tabVal_unit.TIME, tabVal_unit.SV_P1, tabVal_unit.STT FROM tabVal_unit WH = '+ @ id_w;
EXEC (@insert)


SET @count = 0
WHILE @pocet <@num_point
BEGIN
SET @ count = @ count + 1;
SET @ count = CAST (@ count AS varchar)

IF @pocet> 0 AND @pocet <= 9
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal_00' + @ count;
SET @ Bod_ = 'Bod_00' + @ count;
END
IF @pocet> = 10 AND @pocet <= 99
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal_0' + @ count;
SET @ Bod_ = 'Bod_0' + @ count;
END
IF @count * = 100
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal _' + @ count;
SET @ Point_ = 'Point _' + @ count;
END
SET @Update = 'UPDATE' + @ tbl_name + 'SET' + @ tbl_name + '.' + @ Bod_ + '='+@tab_val_+'.VAL FROM' + @ tbl_name + 'INNER JOIN' + @ tab_val_ + 'ON' + @tbl_name + '. ID_R ='+@tab_val_+'.ID_R';
EXEC (@Update)
END

if @duplex = 11
BEGIN
SET @count = 200
--SET @num_point = @pocet + @num_point
SET @Cycle = @pocet + @num_point
--PRINT @Cycle
WHILE @pocet <@Cycle
BEGIN
SET @ count = @ count + 1;
SET @ count = CAST (@ count AS varchar)
IF @pocet> 200 AND @pocet <= @ Cycle
BEGIN
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal _' + @ count;
SET @ Point_ = 'Point _' + @ count;
END
SET @Alter_d = 'ALTER TABLE' + @ tbl_name + 'ADD' + @ Bod_ + 'decimal (6,3) NULL';
EXEC (@Alter_d)
END



SET @count = 200
SET @Cycle = @pocet + @num_point
WHILE @pocet <@Cycle
BEGIN
SET @ count = @ count + 1;
SET @ count = CAST (@ count AS varchar)

IF @pocet> 200 AND @pocet <= @ Cycle
BEGIN
--PRINT @pocet
--PRINT @Cycle
--PRINT @num_point
SET @ tab_val_ = 'tabVal _' + @ count;
SET @ Point_ = 'Point _' + @ count;
END
SET @Update_d = 'UPDATE' + @ tbl_name + 'SET' + @ tbl_name + '.' + @ Bod_ + '='+@tab_val_+'.VAL FROM' + @ tbl_name + 'INNER JOIN' + @ tab_val_ + 'ON' + @tbl_name + '. ID_R ='+@tab_val_+'.ID_R';
EXEC (@Update_d)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking to accomplish.  However you have your variable `@tabSta_` declared as a `VARCHAR` variable but you appear to be using it as a `TABLE` variable since you're attempting to select from it in the query `SELECT DESC_POINT FROM @tabSta_ WHERE id_w = @ id_w`.  If you're planning on using that variable as a table, you need to declare it as a table variable as below with the appropriate columns, just as you would with a `CREATE TABLE` statement.

```
DECLARE @tabSta_ TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(10), col2 VARCHAR(10), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this code pattern. The select statement must return only one value

```
declare @my_variable as varchar(20)

select @my_variable=value from table where id=1
```